# Java Object lists pro & cons

Tags: java, object, casting

I am creating this game in Java and I'm using an priority queue to render my enemies by their Y-value. But I would like to sort an other type of object than the enemy object. As all objects in java inherits from the Object class I thought I'd just make the queue of the Object type and typecast the enemies. So I was wondering if there is any major cons about doing it this way?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide more details with example code and/or a more detailed description of what you want to do?

Comment: I have a Priority Queue of Javas default class: Object, which all classes by default inherits from. I then put 2 different objects in it. And when using the objects I type-cast it to access the functions. Is it a good or bad solution to be able to put 2 different objects in the same Priority Queue?

Comment: How are these two different objects related?

Comment: From the limited information you have given, this sounds like a bad idea. I suggest creating a queue of the specific class objects which you are using. This is the point of generics in Java. If you have several different, related classes, you should create a superclass which can be used as the type for the references in the queue.

Comment: I know I could create a superclass for these objects, but what would be the difference from using javas superclass Object?

Comment: With that said, we need a more specific question in order to give a specific answer. Please read [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) for some tips about asking good questions that will get good answers. In particular, you should add some code to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are several advantages to creating a queue of a custom superclass rather than relying on the generic `Object` grandparent of all classes. Some of these include

1. You don't have to use any casts to access the elements of your queue.
2. The compiler finds errors for you. Examples include trying to add an reference to the queue that cannot be later cast to the type you expect.

The ideas you are asking about are covered in any good Java text. I strongly suggest that you do some reading and/or online research for more details about this topic.

Comment: The thing is I want to render the objects depending on the Y-axis in order to make it look like the objects are "behind" objects. And the the monsters is so much bigger than the other object that I cant find it necessary to make a whole superclass that just holds positions, because then I would need to typecast the objects anyway to get the specific methods. I am thinking of making a pq of Object and then have a method that returns another list of the objects type holding the objects references.

Comment: @RasmusAppelkvist It sounds like you have a lot of design issues that you need to work out. Perhaps you have each class doing too many things. You might want to look for ways you can split up your classes into more manageable pieces of code.